# How to extract the value of the attribute picture list using Selenium Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have this code bellow

```
<div class="gallery-list">
<figure class="figure" ng-class="profileGallery.css" profile-item-remove="9>
<a href="https://#" data-login="" gallery-modal="9" rel="nofollow">
<picture sl-video-preview="https://movie.mp4" sl-safe="" class="ng-isolate- 
scope sl-safe">
</a>
</figure>
<figure class="figure hd" ng-class="profileGallery.css" profile-item- 
 remove="9>
<a href="https://#" data-login="" gallery-modal="9" rel="nofollow">
<picture sl-video-preview="https://movie.mp4" sl-safe="" class="ng-isolate- 
 scope sl-safe">
</a>
</figure>
<figure class="figure" ng-class="profileGallery.css" profile-item-remove="9>
<a href="https://#" data-login="" gallery-modal="9" rel="nofollow">
<picture sl-video-preview="https://movie.mp4" sl-safe="" class="ng-isolate- 
 scope sl-safe">
</a>
  </figure>
<div>
```

Xpath

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 
20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='gallery- 
list']/figure[@class='figure hd']/a/picture[@class='ng-isolate-scope sl- 
safe']"))).get_attribute("sl-video-preview"))
```

With this xpath code it is possible to get one record of attribute figure, but this is dynamic, some times I have one, two, three, twelve or fifty.
How to get all occurrences of attribute value by xpath sl-video-preview with dynamic size of list occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you were pretty close. For the `<figure>` nodes you have considered both the classes `figure` and `hd` but all of them doesn't have them and you need to traverse them all. Additionally, instead of `visibility_of_element_located()` you need to use `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("sl-video-preview") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.gallery-list figure.figure picture.ng-isolate-scope.sl-safe")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("sl-video-preview") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='gallery-list']//figure[contains(@class, 'figure')]//picture[@class='ng-isolate-scope sl-safe']")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is in Java.

```
// Find All elements at once
    list<WebElement> pictureURLs = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='gallery- 
    list']//a/picture"));
//Loop through the element list & print the required attributes
    for(WebElement pictureurl:pictureURLs)
    {
    System.out.println(pictureurl..get_attribute("sl-video-preview"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to amend your function to use [find_elements_by_xpath](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_xpath) which returns a [List](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp) of [WebElements](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement) as your current code returns only single (first) WebElement which matches the locator provided.

Suggested code change:

```
pictures = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//picture")))
for picture in pictures:
    print(picture.get_attribute('sl-video-preview'))
```

Going forward you could consider refactoring your code to use [Page Object Model Design Pattern](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Design+Patterns+-+Page+Object+Model), this way you can get benefit from [lazy initialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization) approach and will not have to define [Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) all the time.

Comment: hi. this example sometimes works, but return Nome value or return ` AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute find_elements `

Comment: hi i find the problem, not is in xpath, i put a time.sleep(5) after login page to resolve timeout in component.. thanks again for the help..